# Questionable Failed Review Audit

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I just failed the following review audit, and not entirely sure why this question should not be closed:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/13462036

(Image form):

[image: Image Form]

The question is essentially a *here's my table, and my expected result.  Gimmie teh codez* with nothing else added.

My only guess for why it thinks it's a good question is because of the high number of upvotes.

Am I incorrect on my assessment here?

Comment: `not entirely sure why this question should not be closed`... well technically, lack of effort is not a close reason.  What close reason did you want to use?  That being said, it does seem like a poor quality question with little research effort, but that in of itself isn't a close reason.

Comment: They throw in a highly upvoted post now and then you verify that you are paying attention and don't try to destroy something that SO users like a lot.  Why such a question gets 7 helpful votes does tend to be hard to fathom.  It is formatted nicely, perhaps.  Or the votes are fake, that's common and the kind of fraud that wrecks so many things at SO.  Like audits.  You can't win them all.